# Fast search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, full-text-search

1. Let's have tons of posts.
2. As a user, I want to find all posts containing the words "hello" and "world".
3. Let's say there is a post with this text "Hello world, this place is beautiful".

Now:

- a) Find the text if the user searches for "hello",
- b) Find the text
  if the user searches for "hello", "world",
- c) Don't find the text if the user searches for "hello", "world", "funny".

To reduce the quantity of possible candidates I was thinking about this:

```
for each post (
if number_of_search_words == number_of_post_words -> proceed with search logic
if number_of_search_words < number_of_post_words -> proceed with search logic
if number_of_search_words > number_of_post_words -> don't proceed with search logic
)
```

but that would also require an number containing the quantity of words of each post, which leads to more complexity.

Is there an elegant way of solving this?

Comment: Typically, you create an index of all the words in the tons of posts. Then for a multiple word search, you compute the **intersection** or the **union** of the post lists for each word. For example, assume the  index list for "hello" is {1,2,5}, and the index list for "world" is {2,4,5}. A search for posts containing "hello" AND "world" would return posts 2 and 5. But a search for posts containing "hello" OR "world" would return posts 1, 2, 4, and 5.

Answer (score 1):

You must to use bit containers, for example, [BitMagic](http://bitmagic.io/).

- Initially, you assign to each post some sequenced integer ID, postID.
- Thereafter, create N bit containers (N = quantity of search words), each size is maximal postID.
- Thereafter, build indices: parse each post, and for each term from the post, set bit`1` in the term-associated container, with postID as index.

To search:

- get bit containers for your words "hello", "word".
- AND those bit containers.
- Result container will contains bit `1`'s for PostIDs, contains both search terms.